# C# MVVM Pass through ObservableCollection with ContentPresenter and Bind in Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a WPF MVVM application that shows me a list of groups. The example is kept extra simple, for the described case it is probably too complicated. For this I created three UserControls:

- SideMenuControl (should show a TextBox and the list of groups)
- GroupListControl (should contain the single groups)
- GroupControl (should show the name of the group)

It should looks like this:

```
 ________________________
| SideMenuControl        |
|                        |
| Hello World            |
|  ____________________  |
| |GroupListControl    | |
| |                    | |
| |  ________________  | |
| | | Group1         | | |
| | | Group2         | | |
| | |________________| | |
| |____________________| |
|________________________|
```

However, I don't understand how to pass the *ObservableCollection* ***Groups*** to the GroupListControl. I guess it must succeed with **DataContext**, **Content** and/or **ItemSource**. Can anyone help me further?

**GroupControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.GroupControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</UserControl>
```

**GroupListControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.GroupListControl"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:GroupControl />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer> 
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**SideMenuControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.SideMenuControl"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="Hello World"/>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>    
</UserControl>
```

**GroupViewModel.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class GroupViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private Group _group;
        public string Name
        {
            get => _group.Name;
            set => SetProperty(_group.Name, value, _group, (model, name) => model.Name = name);
        }

        public GroupViewModel(Group model)
        {
            _group = model;
        }
    }
}
```

**GroupCollectionViewModel.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class GroupCollectionViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> Groups { get; set; }

        public GroupCollectionViewModel()
        {
            Groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>();
            Groups.Add(new GroupViewModel(new Group { Name = "Group1" }));
            Groups.Add(new GroupViewModel(new Group { Name = "Group2" }));
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="GroupList" Height="450" Width="800">
    <local:SideMenuControl
        DataContext="{Binding Groups}">
    </local:SideMenuControl>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new GroupCollectionViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If I replace the **ContentPresenter** element with the **ScrollViewer** element from *GroupListControl.xaml* (and remove the word *Groups* from the Binding Element) in *SideMenuControl.xaml* like below, I get the result that I want. But how can I achieve this with UserControls (GroupListControl and GroupControl)?

**SideMenuControl.xaml (modified)**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.SideMenuControl"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="Hello World"/>
                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:GroupControl />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>    
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Your issue is hard to understand without seeing where you actually instanciate the GroupListControl. I also don't understand your file naming, eg. "GroupListControl.cs", where the file is an xaml template, not cs code - should be GroupListControl.xaml? Can you just put an ObservableCollection inside the view model of GroupListControl.cs and put your data in it when you initialize the GroupListControl?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have corrected the file names. GroupListControl is not directly instantiated, maybe that is the problem. I don't know where this should be done. I have an ObservableCollection in GroupCollectionViewModel, so I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: What I mean is: in the code you shared, you never actually use GroupListControl. The Usercontrol isn't placed in any of the XAML templates (which would also instantiate it.) I'm also confused by this: `public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> Groups { get; set; }` GroupViewModel should, according to the name, be a ViewModel, but you seem to just be using it as a container for your Group data with no tie to any view. Is there a reason behind the naming?

If you utilize the ViewModels of your views (eg. the class `GroupListControl`), your problem should be trivial :)

Comment: The ObservableCollection Groups is bound MainWindow.xaml: <local:SideMenuControl DataContext="{Binding Groups}">.I think I need to add ContentTemplate to GroupListControl in this SideMenuControl element. But so far I have no success with this.

Comment: Pass from where? What exactly is your question? Could you please narrow it down a bit? You don't "pass" anything to a `UserControl`.

Comment: In SideMenuControl.xaml I have the ContentPresenter element. Somehow I have to specify that the data (DataContext="{Binding Groups}") should be displayed with the GroupListControl. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want is a [DependencyProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0) on your `GroupListControl`. E.g., within your GroupListControl.cs file:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupsProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Groups",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>),
        typeof(GroupListControl)
    );

public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> Groups
{
    get => (ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>)GetValue(GroupsProperty);
    set => SetValue(GroupsProperty, value);
}
```

You can then bind to this in your XAML whenever you use a `GroupListControl`.

Comment: Looks like a different approach to me that I haven't pursued yet. Nevertheless, I am missing the connection here as well. Where exactly do I instantiate GroupListControl?

Comment: You would instantiate it wherever you want to use it, e.g., in a Window, Page, UserControl, etc. Does that help?

Comment: Can you relate it to my example a little more specifically? Where would I specify the GroupListControl? In the SideMenuControl instead of the ContentPresenter? Or as a child element of the ContentPresenter? Or directly in the MainWindow as a child element of the SideMenuControl element?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to have a ContentPresenter in SideMenuControl? Where/how are you planning to specify the content?

Comment: It is not really necessary. I'm trying to learn MVVM and XAML and I'm not getting anywhere. Somewhere I have to specify that I want to display my DataContext (Groups) with the GroupListControl in the ContentPresenter.

Comment: Yes, you could specify GroupListControl instead of the ContentPresenter, and if GroupListControl has the DependencyProperty Groups on it, you could say `<GroupListControl Groups="{Binding}">`.